# Connect UITable Cells to Different Storyboards?

Tags: uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Is it possible to link static cells in a UITable to different storyboards?

If so.. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
In case anyone else runs into this issue here's the solution..

Make sure to add on your main controller all the .h files
For me they would be

```
#import "tabbar26.h"
```

Now here is the code that I added to make it work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


            if (row == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"hi");

        }

        if (row == 27)
        {
        }
 }

return cell;
}
```

This part above, really is not needed. I was just using it for Logging.

BELOW is what you need really :)

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath      {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (row == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"hi2");
    }

if (row == 25)
{
    NSLog(@"bye2");
    UIStoryboard *tabbar26 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"tabbar26" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *Tab1_ViewController = [tabbar26 instantiateInitialViewController];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:Tab1_ViewController animated:(YES)];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```